# Trying to represent a nested for loop as a Java Stream, but confused

Tags: java, java-stream

Im trying to understand streams in java better, and im just trying to represent a nested for loop as a stream but im struggling to figure it out.

Ive tried a handful of things, but I cant seem to grasp it.

For example, something like this.

```
for (Profile profile : profiles) {
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getUserId().equals(profile.getProfileId())) {
           profile.setField(false);
        }
    }
}
```

How would one do this as a stream in Java?

Comment: This particular example doesn't really benefit from streams at all, and boils down to just nested calls to `forEach` that look almost exactly the same as the original.

Comment: Since you are iterating over two unrelated collections, then streams couldn't really be used here

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to understand stream, but let me say that the `for` version is not worse and the `Stream` version is not better: performance test and intuition will probably help you there, as well as readability.

That said, you problem here is that your second look require the first one to work:

```
profiles.stream()
        .filter(profile -> users.stream() 
                                .anyMatch(user -> user.getUserId().equals(profile.getProfileId())))
        .forEach(profile -> profile.setField(false));
```

This is strictly not the same as your for loop: you call `setField` several time per profile, while in the stream version it is only ever done if there is one matching user. I assumed that `setField` is a setter, and as such since its value is constant, it should not matter if it is called once or several times.

I would advise you not to use the first stream in this case, or limit yourself to `forEach`:

```
profiles.forEach(profile -> profile.setField(!users.stream() 
                                   .anyMatch(user -> user.getUserId().equals(profile.getProfileId())));
```

Which could be simplified by first getting all user ids and using contains from the generated set:

```
   var userIds = users.stream().map(User::getUserId).collect(toSet());
   profiles.forEach(profile -> profile.setField(!userIds.contains(profile.getProfileId()));
```

Comment: `anyMatch` is not the same as last matched, this might be an incompatible change. On another note, why is there an assumption of comparing `id` with `==`whiile in question `equals` is used? And your last code sets the `field` attribute of some profiles to `true` as well, which is again not compatible with the existing code behavior.

Comment: That is a matter of logic and laziness: the logic here is reading the `for*2` version which calls `profile.setField(false)` if there is a matching user.
I expected the method to be a simple setter: if it was _counting_ number of calls, this would be truly different but I would rather choose a better name for it.
As for `user.id == profile.id`, as said _I simplified the getter out of laziness_ So yes, it should be `user.getUserId().equals(profile.getProfileId())`.

Comment: Simplifying getter doesn't mean you can't compare `user.id.equals(profile.id)`.  I wasn't really talking about counting the calls. Just test your method and the one in question over a sample data where some profiles are not under selected `userIds` but were previously assigned the value `false` for `field` attribute.